# Making this code pull from specific timeframe tradingview

Tags: pine-script

how would I go about adding MTF to a pinescript on tv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [request.security()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html) function for that.

Below code would display the daily SMA value on your chart no matter what your chart's timeframe is.

```
//@version=4
study(title="High Time Frame MA", overlay=true)
src = close, len = 9
out = sma(src, len)
out1 = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', out)
plot(out1)
```

Comment: still getting an error with that, I thought the security function was deprecated?

Comment: Actually think I got it, does this seem right? Edit above

Comment: The `security()` function has been moved to a new namespace with version 5. My example is from version 4, sorry about that. You need to use `request.security()` as you did already. And yes, it does seem right.